# Polynomials equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I am trying to find the common solutions of this equations: $$ 2x^4+x^3-5x^2+2x=0  $$
$$ 2(2x-1)^{1998}+(4x-1)^{1997}=4x+1 $$. My idea is to solve the first one. I find the solutions:$ x=1$ , $x=0$ , $x=1/2$ , $x=-2 $. The solution $x=0$ confirms the other equation. My problem is that i dont know how to show that $x=-2  $ is not a solution of the second equation. For $x=-2$ the second one becames $ 2(5)^{1998}-9^{1997}-7=0  $

Comment: $9^{1997}$ is hugely bigger than the other term. There are other ways, like working mod $4$, but size is perhaps the most obvious reason we don't have equality.

Comment: $7$ is relatively negligible. But $1998 \log 2 \log 5 $ is much smaller than $1997 \log 9$

Answer (score 1):

Since $\;1997\;$ is prime we get that $\;k^{1997}=k\pmod{1997}\;$ , so:

$$2\cdot5^{1998}-9^{1997}-7=2\cdot5^2-9-7\pmod{1997}=34\pmod{97}\neq0\pmod{1997}$$

and thus $\;-2\;$ indeed is not a root of the second polynomial

Answer (score 0):

$$ 2(5)^{1998}-9^{1997}-7=0  $$
The first term ends with a $0$, and the second with a $9$.

Thus, the last digit of the result would be $4$, and the result cannot be $0$.

Answer (score 0):

$2\cdot 5^{1998}$ is clearly congruent with $0$ modulo $10$.Besides $9^n$ is congruent with $1$ or $9$ modulo $10$ so, reducing modulo $10$ your last equality you have $-8$ or$-6$ congruent with $0$ modulo $10$, absurde.